# file_get_contents returning empty result

Tags: php, json

I'm, using `file_get_contents` to get the output in JSON format

```
$queryurl = "http://cloud.softpanda.com.au:9874/loyalty/customer/query-account?user=foo&pass=bar&format=json";
$queryurl = $queryurl . "&number=" . urlencode($cardnumber);
$queryurl = $queryurl . "&pin=" . urlencode($cardpin);

$queryresult = @file_get_contents($queryurl);
$jsonresult = @json_decode($queryresult, true);
```

the issue is that result is displayed when I go to the URL manually, but when I print `$queryresult` I get nothing. It is showing an empty result. When using this on my local server it is working fine, but when I use it on live (remote) server then I'm getting this issue.

Comment: If you removed the horrible operator that is `@` you'd get your error.

Comment: Maybe you should actually use `file_get_contents` instead of `file_put_contents`?

Comment: I got this error after removing @ operator:-      Warning: file_get_contents(http://cloud.softpanda.com.au:9874/loyalty/customer/query-account?user=ivapine-web&pass=GqJcSPNblD&format=json&number=YY&pin=AA)  [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home/content/63/11277163/html/melissa/loyalty/myaccount.php on line 64

Comment: yes I am using file_get_contents instead of file_put_contents. It ws mistake in original post

Comment: @Rohit 2 things. First of all, are you sure that you're allowed to contact servers on port 9874 with your server provider? Secondly, make sure that you **never** post credentials in stackoverflow questions, as anyone then can see them.

Comment: @h2ooooooo not sure if you should edit his source code because it might be the reason he is getting the wrong results..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli The only changed I've made was removing credentials and changing `file_put_contents` to `file_get_contents` based on "*yes I am using file_get_contents instead of file_put_contents. It ws mistake in original post*". Feel free to rollback, if you feel that this is wrong.

Comment: @h2ooooooo do I need to contact with my hosting provider to check if I am allowed to contact server on port 9874 ?

Comment: @h2ooooooo, yes that was a good call. I noticed that you made the multiple lines a single one, and that could change the result.. Anyway it was just a reminder to exercise caution when editing code.

Comment: @Rohit First check what the problem is. Does `file_get_contents('http://www.google.com')` work for you? If not, then you're not allowed to open streams at all.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I checked the same code on my local server it is working fine. But on live server it is not working.

Comment: @h2ooooooo do I need to contact with cloud.softpanda.com.au or with my hosting server where my files are place regarding the port 9874  ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow

```
allow_url_fopen
```

in your php.ini config file.  It is often disabled on live servers for security reasons.  You can check if it is disabled by doing a phpinfo() check.